# How can I easily iterate over this loop on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a small program to get a password input from the user and then evaluate the password according to some metrics. Them being upper case, lower case, numbers and special characters. I then calculate the strength of the password by calculating how many of these criteria are satisfied. How can I do the iteration of the loop where I find how many upper case, lower case, numbers and special characters are there?

I already have a working code but I think the process could be done more efficiently. What do you think?

```
import string

password = input("Enter the password: ")

upper_case = any([1 if c in string.ascii_uppercase else 0 for c in password])
lower_case = any([1 if c in string.ascii_lowercase else 0 for c in password])
special = any([1 if c in string.punctuation else 0 for c in password])
digits = any([1 if c in string.digits else 0 for c in password])

characters = [upper_case, lower_case, special, digits]

length = len(password)

score = 0
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.11

Comment: Which loop are you referring to? I don't understand what you mean by "how can I iterate over this loop" because if you have a loop you are already iterating by definition.

Comment: Sorry. Loop wasn't the best description. I was referring to the part where I'm defining and counting numbers, special characters, etc.

Comment: You can make it clear by giving some sample in-/outputs?

Comment: You could put `string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase`, etc. into a list and then iterate over that list, though I think the idea from the answer below of just using predicates like `.isupper()` is preferable.

Comment: @DanielHao for example: +1 if there are numbers in the password, +1 if there is a special character, +1 if the password is above a certain length.

Comment: Do you mean that you want `sum(characters)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, and I do that later in the program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're complicating things a bit too much:

```py
import string

password = input("Enter the password: ")

upper_case = any(c.isupper() for c in password)
lower_case = any(c.islower() for c in password)
special = any(c in password for c in string.punctuation) # I think there isn't a easier way to do it
digits = any(c.isdigit() for c in password)

characters = [upper_case, lower_case, special, digits]

length = len(password)

score = 0
```